# Remove all alarms at once

Tags: 8.1, nokia-lumia-1020

I've been using Cortana to set alarms to remind me to do things after a few minutes e.g. `Set an alarm for 20 minutes`. This has worked fine up to today, when Cortana responded with `Whoops I can't add any more alarms`. I opened up the Alarms app and found that each of my alarms are saved and there must be a max number of allowed alarms!

How can I remove all the saved alarms without going through each one manually and deleting it?

Answer (score 2):

The fast answer is; you can't.

But in order to delete all a bit faster, use the manage [image: Manage] button to see a bin pictograph left to every alarm, that way you can just spam at the top left corner of the screen to remove all the alarms.